# Bootsrap not working with spring boot thymeleaf pdf template

Tags: spring-boot, pdf, thymeleaf

I have a problem adding bootstrap into my thymeleaf template. I want to export that template as pdf.
Bootsrap is not applied to my template. I tried webjars and static bootsrap js and css files but it doesn't work. Is there any other way that i can do? These are webjars links that I have added inside html;

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css}" type="text/css"/>
    <script th:src="@{webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js}"></script>
</head>
```

This is java code;

```
public byte[] getReportByTestId(Long testId, String templateName) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Optional<Test> test = testRepository.findById(testId);

    if (test.isPresent()) {
        Test _test = test.get();

        ObjectMapper oMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        Map map = oMapper.convertValue(_test, Map.class);

        Context context = new Context();
        context.setVariables(map);

        String htmlContentToRender = templateEngine.process(templateName, context);

        String xHtml = xhtmlConvert(htmlContentToRender);

        ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();

        String baseUrl = FileSystems
                .getDefault()
                .getPath("src", "main", "resources", "templates")
                .toUri()
                .toURL()
                .toString();
        renderer.setDocumentFromString(xHtml, baseUrl);
        renderer.layout();
        ByteOutputStream outputStream = new ByteOutputStream();
        renderer.createPDF(outputStream);
        byte[] pdfAsBytes = outputStream.getBytes();

        outputStream.close();

        return pdfAsBytes;
    }

    return null;
}

private String xhtmlConvert(String html) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
    tidy.setInputEncoding("UTF-8");
    tidy.setOutputEncoding("UTF-8");
    tidy.setXHTML(true);
    ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(html.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    tidy.parseDOM(inputStream, outputStream);
    return outputStream.toString("UTF-8");
}
```

When I add like this;

```
<script th:src="@{../static/vendor/bootstrap5/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
```

It partially works. Only colors are applied.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You will need to add more information if you want help. How are you generating the PDF? Does the Bootstrap styling work in the browser?

Comment: I have added also java code. I am trying to generate pdf with html template created with bootsrap.